# Can I omit the "is" in "a lower price than is actually intended to be charged"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, omissibility

I came across the following sentence when I looked up the meaning of "low-ball".

> The low-ball is a persuasion and selling technique in which an item or service is offered **at a lower price than is actually intended to be charged**, after which the price is raised to increase profit.

Can I omit the "is" and say "at a lower price than actually intended"?

Comment: If you do that, I'd also omit *to be charged*.

Comment: @JasonBassford - you run the risk of it being interpreted as a mistake.  I listed it for $10 when but I intended to list it for $100.    (In general though, I tend to associate *low-ball* with offers to buy rather than offers to sell.  If I list my car for $40,000.00 and some calls up and offers me $20k he's trying to low-ball me. )

Comment: You can and why would you want to, please? How would that be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if the same verb can work in both the independent and subordinate clause, it is permissible and quite common to omit the verb. This is called an *elliptical clause*. Here are a couple examples with the implied verb in parentheses:

> Bill is taller than I (am).

And this example has an adverb and a past participle, but only an implied verb:

> Indeed, "L'Ormindo" is among those works that are more often heard about than (are) actually heard.

Answer (score -1):

‘Actually’ is an adverb. ‘Is’ is a verb. The definition of an adverb is ‘a word that modifies a verb, adjective, another adverb, determiner, noun phrase, clause, or sentence.’ I don’t see how you could remove the verb and keep the adverb, since it is modifying the verb ‘is’ in the sentence.

Comment: Not really. "Is" is a helper verb in this case, and "actually" is modifying "intended", so the helper verb can be removed without destroying the sentence, but it would sound odd to the ear.

Comment: @lux If this were [ell.se] you could expand your comment into an answer. I am voting to migrate the question there.